# Simple way to use a LongListSelector to group a list alphabetically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

i want to use the `LongListSelector` to groupe a list of entries alphabetically.
acutally i'm unsing a normal `ListBox` and it looks like:

- Andhed
- Bdihed
- Cndie

I want to groupe all items like:

- A
- Andhed
- B
- Bdihed
- C
- Cndie

I know i can do it with the `LongListSelector` the problem is, that i dont want to change my data, its a simple `List<String>` is this possible? i dont want to add a additional structure like a groupe (e.g. A) which contains the items (e.g. Andhed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `LongListSelector` you have to group your data before associating it with the control. This isn't so bad, especially if you use patterns such as Model-View-ViewModel.

As an alternative, I have written a jump list control which is presented here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/01/a-windows-phone-7-jump-list-control/

With this control you use a `CategoryProvider`, which will group the data in your list:

```
  <!-- category provider - details how the items are grouped -->
  <l:JumpList.CategoryProvider>
    <l:AlphabetCategoryProvider PropertyName="Surname"/>
  </l:JumpList.CategoryProvider>
```